# convert serveral image files to a single djvu file

Tags: jpeg, png, djvu, bmp

Suppose I have serveral BMP image file, say 001.bmp, 002.bmp,..., 100.bmp.
I want to convert these files to a single djvu file, whose first page is the content of 001.bmp, the second page is the content of 002.bmp...etc.

What is the best way (software) to do this task? I don't want to upload those image file to a server, since it takes too much time. On the other hand, I am not restricted to use BMP files, I can also work with PNG or JPG files.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are on Linux. Install the djvulibre packages (on Debian/Ubuntu, it's `apt install djvulibre-bin)`, cd to the path where you have your images and run the following:

```bash
for x in *.jpg; do c44 -dpi 300 $x; done
djvm -c ../result.djvu *.djvu
ddjvu -format=pdf myfile.djvu myfile.pdf
```

Sources:

- http://www.vitki.net/book/page/converting-jpeg-scans-or-djvu-files-pdf
- http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Creating_a_DjVu_file

On Windows you could follow these steps on cygwin, WSL or similar.

Comment: Note: you may want to add `-percent 100` or similar option after `-dpi 300`, otherwise image quality in the resulting DJVU (and thus PDF) file may be quite bad.

Answer (score 3):

For color pages:

```
pages=pg1.djvu
c44 -dpi 300 pg1.jpg pg1.djvu
```

For black/white:

```
for (( i = 2; i <= $N; i++ )); do
  echo $i
  convert pg$i.jpg pg$i.pbm
  cjb2 pg$i.pbm pg$i.djvu
  pages="$pages pg$i.djvu"
done
```

Join all pages:

```
djvm -c book.djvu  $pages
```

Comment: Since `c44` takes jpg's why do you suggest doing the conversion to pbm specifically for black and white?

Comment: BW uses a much less memory then color. `cjb2` works only with `pbm` files if I proper remember...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple cores while conversion, so it will be much much ... much faster :

```
$ CPU_N="6"; DPI="100"; for i in `ls *.JPG`  ; do echo "$i --> ${i%.JPG}.djvu" ; c44  -dpi "$DPI"   $i   ${i%.JPG}.djvu &  { while [[  $( ps aux | grep c44 | grep -v grep | wc -l )  -eq "$CPU_N" ]] ; do  sleep 1 ; done ; };      done;   { while [[  $( ps aux | grep c44 | grep -v grep | wc -l )  -ge 1 ]] ; do  echo "wait.."; sleep 1 ; done ; }; echo "done"
```

CPU_N = a number of cores you want to use for conversion.
DPI = set dpi for djvu files.

Actually -dpi setting of c44 command doesnt do anything usefull, however it is another story.