# converting scanned imaged into a single DjVu file

Tags: conversion, djvu, image-conversion

AFAIK there are several ways to do this on Linux. I'm a Window's user. Any way to do it on Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/519767/convert-serveral-image-files-to-a-single-djvu-file

Comment: Not duplicate. The answer says: Assuming you are on "LINUX" ... and the question did not say anything about Windows. Definitely those odd-looking codes are not for Windows.